# SAP HANA Cloud cocpit

Tags: c#, sap

Помогите разобраться. Сделал приложение, которое авторизируется на SAP HANA Cloud cockpit. Для авторизации используется OAuth2 протокол.
Все хорошо, токены получаю и могу дальше с ними работать.

Но теперь самое главное: после того, как я авторизировался, мне необходимо послать GET запрос на одну из API-шек SAP HANA. В частности интерисует любой АПИ связанный с финансами: ну там информация по счетам например и тому подобное. Как это сделать? Какова структура запроса?

Я делал так:

https://oauthasservices-XXXXXXXXXtrial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/api/FinancialPlanData

Но в ответ приходит какая-то ерунда:

{
code: "87d74b1a-412e-4038-9aa5-7e814e7b012e"
}

Как правильно обратиться к АПИ SAP HANA? Спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: ссылку на документацию запроса, который вы хотите составить, можно?

Comment: https://my.openconnectors.ext.hanatrial.ondemand.com/api-docs/platform/users    Конечно, вот линк.

Comment: Это 'ерунда' судя по всему ид запроса SOAP который принят, вы должны с какой-то переодичностью стучаться в сервис передавая обратно этот ид. Как только данные по вашему запросу будут сформированы, они будут отосланы вам и удалены из очереди на сервере. Важно - Коннект за данными инициирует вы. Подробней наверняка в документации этого варезника описано.